# Objectify to query datastore with orderBy GeoPt

Tags: google-app-engine, location, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I want to query the datastore using Objectify with orderBy Geopt to get the data sorted with closest position.

I tried filter

```
GeoPt geoPt = filterWrapper.getGeoPt();
Query.StContainsFilter geoFilter = new Query.StContainsFilter("location", new Query.GeoRegion.Circle(geoPt, 5000));
```

But it just filters the data and not sorting.

So is any other way to sort/order by Geopt in datastore with objectify